I just made a BTC purchase i have my wallet address but i dont know what site or app its in?
Last month I made a transaction using a bitcoin address with Kraken I have all of the transaction information. And my wallet address but I don't know where it went. Or what site holds the Bitcoin address Bruce? How do I fand where the address is located? Website app or exchange, is it possible to find that?  To clarify, I sent it from Kraken to the site I'm looking for.

Have you checked your email account for a "sign-up confirmation" or similar?

Generally speaking, it is not feasible to use an address alone to locate a business, a website or a non-custodial wallet which has control over and is able to spend money at that address.
Even if your address was one known to be often reused by one of the more prominent of the thousands of businesses that offer Bitcoin related accounts, you would need more than knowledge of a Bitcoin address to gain access to a customer's account.

Related:

How do I find the exchange an address belongs to
I have lost my wallet, what can I do?

